# SOQL Join for Account & Contact Data

Tags: php, performance, soql

I use a Query to get all Contacts that were changed in the last "timeframe" like this:

```
SELECT AccountId, Id, Email, FirstName, LastName FROM Contact WHERE LastModifiedDate >= $timeframe
```

I also Need the Account name but for now I only make an additional Query like this:

```
SELECT Name FROM Account WHERE Id = '$AccountId'
```

How can I combine thees two so I only need one Query and have one result set?
I tried to make a Join like with normal SQL and even tried some versions I found here and on the Docs but i seem to not get it right...

Comment: What are your tables and how are they related?

Comment: There is an Account Table with Data about the Company and a Contact Table with the data about a specific contact as you can see in my Selects - Please be mindfull that we talk about SOQL for Salesforce and not SQL.

Answer (score 0):

This should get your result : SELECT AccountId, (select name from Account__r), Email, FirstName, LastName FROM Contact WHERE LastModifiedDate >= $timeframe

Comment: Sadly not - Account is not a custom field like in your query, its the Account Table with the Information for an Account (Name, BillingAddress etc.)
If I use SELECT AccountId, Id, (SELECT Name FROM Account), Email, FirstName, LastName FROM Contact LIMIT 10;

I get a return from SF:
ERROR at Row:1:Column:41
Didn't understand relationship 'Account' in FROM part of query call.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Account.Name FROM Contact WHERE LastModifiedDate >= $timeframe
```

You don't need to append `__r` for relationships pre-defined by Salesforce.